# Why am I getting 4 results in reverse_related_entries?

Tags: relationships, reverse-related-entries

EE 2.5.5. I've got a {exp:channel:entries} on products channel. Inside I have a {reverse_related_entries id="reviews"}. I'm getting 4 reviews, when there are only 2. The first 2 are blank. I have 2 products entries, but only displaying 1 product based on URL.

When I go to the other product, I still get 4 reviews, but they're all blank.

Thanks for your help.

Update: Here's the full code for the product page:

```
{embed='includes/header'}

{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="1" }
<div id="hero"><img src="{hero_image}" /></div>
{embed='includes/topnav'}
{if no_results}
<p>Unknown product.</p>
{/if}
<div id="prodinfo">
    <h1>{title}</h1>

    <div id="description" class="desc">{product_description}</div>
    <div id="ulimagescontainer">
    <ul class="prodimages">
        {reverse_related_entries }
        <li>
        <a href="{product_image_video:large}"><img src="{product_image_video:tiny}" /></a>
        </li>
        {/reverse_related_entries}
    </ul>
    </div> <!-- END #ulimagescontainer -->
    <div class="clearboth"></div>

    {if product_features > ''}
    <div id="productfeatures">
    <h3>Features</h3>
    {product_features}
    </div> <!-- END #productfeatures -->
    <div class="clearboth"></div>
    {/if}

    {if vehicle_callouts > ''}
    <div id="vehicle_callouts">
    <img src="{vehicle_callouts}" />
    </div>
    <div class="clearboth"></div>
    {/if}

    {reverse_related_entries id="product_reviews" }
    {if no_reverse_related_entries}
    {if:else}
    {if count == 1}
    <div id="product_reviews">
        <h3>Reviews</h3>
    {/if}

    <div class="reviewitem">
        <div class="synopsis">
        {review_synopsis}
        </div>
        <div class="author">{review_author}</div>
        <div class="link"><a href="{review_link}" target="_blank">{review_publication}</a></div>
    </div>

    {if count == total_results}
    </div>
    <div class="clearboth"></div>
    {/if}
    {/if}
    {/reverse_related_entries}

</div> <!-- END #prodinfo -->
{/exp:channel:entries}


{embed='includes/footer'}
```

Comment: Please post complete code samples. What you've provided isn't enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the syntax for `related_entries` and `reverse_related_entries`. It's `related_entries` which gets the `id` parameter (to signify which field you're asking for). `reverse_related_entries` expects a `channel` parameter (among other options).

([See docs.](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#reverse-related-entries-tag-pair))

So your lower `reverse_related_entries` tag should look more like this:

```
{reverse_related_entries channel="reviews"}
{if count == 1}
    <div id="product_reviews">
    <h3>Reviews</h3>
{/if}

<div class="reviewitem">
    <div class="synopsis">
        {review_synopsis}
    </div>
    <div class="author">{review_author}</div>
    <div class="link"><a href="{review_link}" target="_blank">{review_publication}</a></div>
</div>

{if count == total_results}
    </div>
    <div class="clearboth"></div>
{/if}
{/reverse_related_entries}
```

(Your `{if no_reverse_related_entries}` conditional was superfluous.)

Likewise, your first `reverse_related_entries` tag pair should follow the same format (it currently has no `channel` parameter).

Comment: Bang on Derek. Thanks. I understand why the conditional was superfluous: I'm testing for count. Not crazy about that pattern; but it is what it is.